# Accord du participe passé : « Elle s'est fait maquiller... »

Tags: accord, participe-passé, constructions-causatives

Est-ce qu'on écrit :

> Elle s'est **fait** maquiller par une esthéticienne.

ou

> Elle s'est **faite** maquiller par une esthéticienne.

Comment: Je voterai bien en faveur de la suppression du (e) dans le titre de cette question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lorsque le participe passé du verbe *faire* est **immédiatement suivi d'un infinitif**, alors il échappe aux règles d'accord générales et reste rigoureusement **invariable** =>

Elle s'est **fait** maquiller, virer, embaucher, gronder, avoir, faire, manger...

Comment: C'est en effet la norme, mais l'usage varie.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez : *L'usage varie* ? Hmmm... de l'accord au féminin ?... bien fol qui s'y fie alors... ;-)